# atom editor indentation error with Python

Tags: python, indentation, atom-editor

I am new to atom, so I opened my existing code using atom and modified few lines, then when I tried running the code with python, I get the following error:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I realized that Atom editor does indent my code differently to what I had. refer to the attached picture below showing the different indentation styles. line 1300 is the old indentation and 1301 is the one created by Atom

How can I fix this without modifying my 1000+ line code and so that atom uses the same style of indentation.

[image]

Comment: "I realized that Atom editor does indent my code differently to what I had. refer to the attached picture below showing the different indentation styles." - did you understand *what text* was being used for the indentation in each case? Did you try *replacing the wrong indentation, with text that matched the correct indentation*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have mixed tabs and spaces in your code. You [should use spaces, always](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

You can use [this plugin](http://discuss.atom.io/t/tabs-to-spaces-package/3653) to quickly fix your code, and please, use only spaces and 4 spaces for each level of indentation.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you should always use spaces instead of tabs?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error while using Atom,I fixed it using below steps.

1. Install notepad++
2. Open the file which has issue(one you have mentioned in question) in notepad++.
3. Go to **View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters**,this will show up where the tabs and where spaces are available.
4. Go to **Edit->Blank Operations->TAB** **to Space** to replace all tabs with spaces.
5. Go to **View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters**,confirm all tabs are replaced with spaces.
6. Save file and reload page,this will fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of Atom, just go to settings > Editor; then scroll down to tab length and change it to 4; then change tab type to soft. This will make the tab key insert 4 spaces instead of a tab character moving forward. You still have to update your previous code using one of the above methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the Atom Text Editor's top menu bar :

> click the Packages tab

> click Whitespace in the dropdown menu

> Choose your preferred option (ie: Convert Spaces to Tabs)

And that will fix this pesky problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).