# IndentationError when adding new line inside code

Tags: python, atom-editor

I'm using Atom as text editor, I wrote a python script that works perfectly:

```
def Name():
   name = 'Foo'
   print name

Name()
```

but now if I try to edit it and add another variable under `name` (e.g. `surname`) I get this error:

```
def Name():
   name = 'Foo'
   surname = 'Bar'
   print name, surname

Name()
```

Prints:

```
surname  = 'Bar'
               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I didn't use spaces, I just made a new line by going at the end of `name = 'Foo'` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: And did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118234/atom-editor-indentation-error-with-python

Comment: Top tip: configure your editor to show whitespace characters (see e.g. https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-is-so-powerful-that-it-blows-my-mind/294)